# Use one single instance of QApplication in python unit test

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, python-unittest

How can I create one single instance of `QApplication`?

Background:

I am testing a couple of widgets implementing `QWidget` in unit tests. For this, I have to create an instance of `QApplication`. The second call to the constructor of `QApplication` results in an exception.

It works with following drawbacks:

- The widget and the `QApplication` are created in `setUpClass(cls)`, marked as `@classmethod`. For creation and maintenance of the tests, this is a pain cause every test has to deal with the same instance of the widget.
- As soon as I have to execute multiple test cases, multiple `QApplication` instances are created and I'm facing a RuntimeError again...

My first working idea was to surround every call to `QApplication()` by a `try except`. But I am not happy with that...

I tried calling `app.quit()`, setting `self.app = None` and `gc.collect()`. None of them worked.

Technology facts:

- Python 3.4
- PySide
- module `unittest`
- Execution in PyCharm and console / script

Answer (score 2):

Use the same `QApplication` instance for all unit tests in your test script.
To use the same `QApplication` instance, instantiate `QApplication` in the global scope of the unit test script.

Use a unique `QWidget` for each unit test.
To use a unique `QWidget` instance, instantiate `QWidget` in `unittest.TestCase.setUp()`

Here is a complete test script example to run from a console.
My environment is similar to yours except I am using:

- PyQt5 instead of PySide
- Jupyter QtConsole instead of PyCharm

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
import unittest

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
"""All tests use the same single global instance of QApplication."""

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
"""The tests individually instantiate the top-level window as a QWidget."""

# Create an application global accessible from all tests.
app= QApplication( sys.argv )

# Define setUp() code used in all tests.
class PyQt_TestFixture( unittest.TestCase ):

    def create_application_window( self ):
        w= QWidget()
        return w

    def setUp( self ):
        self.window= self.create_application_window()

class TestPyQt( PyQt_TestFixture ):
    """Suite of tests. See test fixture for setUp()."""
    def test_QWidget_setWindowTitle( self ):
        """Test that PyQt setWindowTitle() sets the title of the window."""

        # Operate.
        self.window.setWindowTitle( 'Test setWindowTitle' )

        # Check.
        self.assertEqual( self.window.windowTitle(), 'Test setWindowTitle' )

    def test_eachTestUsesUniqueQWidgets( self ):
        """Test that the other test of PyQt setWindowTitle() is not affecting this test."""

        # Check.
        self.assertNotEqual( self.window.windowTitle(), 'Test setWindowTitle' )
        """The windowTitle() is an empty string '' if setWindowTitle() is not called."""

    def test_QWidget_resize( self ):
        """Another example: test that PyQt resize() resizes the window."""

        # Operate.
        self.window.resize( 123, 456 )

        # Check.
        from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
        size= QSize( 123, 456 )
        self.assertEqual( self.window.size(), size )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I found to work best with Pyside6 (should work with 2 too) in test setUp()

```
self.app = QApplication.instance() or QApplication()
```

This should ensure only one instance gets created.